# SIMPLE: Adding in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

Here's some of my code.
When I try to echo `i`, the app crashes.
What's the problem with the code?

```
int i=0;

for (NSDictionary *rowthree in resultsthree) {
i++;
testLabel.text = i;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample is pretty minimal, but at a guess: You can't directly set `testLabel.text = i`, since `text` is an instance of NSString, not an integer. You probably meant:

```
testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
```